# The diff function in sympy doesn't return a number?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm a newbie learning python. I have a question, can you guys help me? This is my code:

```
from sympy import *
def test(f, g, a):
   f1 = f.subs(x, g)
   df1 = diff(f1, x).subs(x, a)
   return df1
print(test((2*(x**2) + abs(x + 1)), (x - 1), -1))

Result: -Subs(Derivative(re(x), x), x, -1) - 8
```

I'm taking the derivative of f(g(x)) with: `f = 2(x^2) + abs(x + 1)`, `g = x - 1` and `x = -1`. When I use `diff` to calculate the result is `-Subs(Derivative(re(x), x), x, -1) - 8`, but when I use the formula `lim x->x0 (f(x) - f(x0))/(x - x0)` I got result is `-9`. I also tried using a calculator to calculate and the result `-9` is the correct result. Is there a way to make diff return -9? Anyone have any help or can give some pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about SymPy to tell you what's going on from its side, but `f` as currently defined isn't everywhere differentiable. In particular, look at when its argument is `-1`. You may need to let SymPy know that you aren't going to ask for the derivative at that point. Indeed, this is something you're implicitly doing when applying the definition of the deriative in your manual calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I see a `re` or `im` appear when I didn't expect them, I am inclined to make the symbols real:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> def test(f, g, a):
...    f1 = f.subs(x, g)
...    df1 = diff(f1, x).subs(x, a)
...    return df1
...
>>> var('x',real=True)
x
>>> print(test((2*(x**2) + abs(x + 1)), (x - 1), -1))
-9
```

Comment: Nice. You might explicitly pinpoint your correction to your answer, i.e. restricting `x` to be a `real`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm still a relative beginner to `sympy` I like to view intermediate results (I even like to do that with `numpy` which I know much better).  Running in `isympy`:

```
In [6]: diff(f1,x)
Out[6]: 
          ⎛      d                 d        ⎞        
          ⎜re(x)⋅──(re(x)) + im(x)⋅──(im(x))⎟⋅sign(x)
          ⎝      dx                dx       ⎠        
4⋅x - 4 + ───────────────────────────────────────────
                               x
```

That expression contains unevaluate `d/dx` and the distinction between the real and imaginary parts of `x`.

Restricting `x` to real as suggested in the other answer produces:

```
In [19]: diff(exp,x)
Out[19]: 4⋅x + sign(x + 1)
```